# Array comparison using SQL 2005. Error converting

Tags: arrays, sql-server-2005, compare

Ok, no idea why a multi-billion dollar company skimps on array functions for their flagship SQL servers This is why people use MySQL Server. Ok, enough ranting. Using SQL 2005.

Let's say i received an array via checkbox from another page using the querystring method:

```
intTask = request.querystring("task")
```

For this example, intTask = "1,3,5"

Then I used the query

```
SELECT user.Task FROM user WHERE (user.Task in (" & intTask & "))
```

This gives an error of:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1, 2' to data type int
```

The array in the User.task column here = 1,2. NVARCHAR is the data type. intTask is a string. No idea why SQL is trying to convert the column to integers when its suppose to be a string comparison. I already know about the SQL injection vulnerability, that taken care of with another script for the page.

OK. Well how does one compare arrays using SQl Server 2005 ? I can't seem to find any SQL functions that will iterate through 2 strings and compare for all matching values.

For example

```
intTask = 1,2

user.task = 3,5,7,2,9
```

Because of the 2's, I should get a recordset because the 2's exist in both arrays

UPDATE

Is there an SQL function that will handle two arrays and iterate through the arrays to find matching items. Something like:

intTask = "1,3,5"

user("task") = "3,5,2"

ARR1 = split(intTask,",")

ARR2 = split(user("task"),",")

for i=0 to UBound(arr1)

```
for j=0 to UBound(arr2)

    if(arr1(i) = arr2(j)) then

       common_found = true

    end if

Next
```

Next

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The array in the User.task column here = 1,2. NVARCHAR is the data type.

because 1,2 are 2 integers and your column is a nvarchar, use '1','2', you might need to prefix win N

take a look at [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Here is a code example

```
create table #test (id nvarchar(20))
insert #test values('1,2')
insert #test values('2,3')
go
```

works

```
select * from #test
where id in (N'1,2')
```

will fail

```
select * from #test
where id in (1,2)
```

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.

If you are only using integers then use varchar, not nvarchar, nvarchar uses double the storage of varchar...of course if you properly normlized the Db you would not have these problems

Comment: +1 -- I had that article bookmarked before and lost it, that's a great article.

Comment: Please provide an example of the use of the "prefix win N" in code. Preferably a complete SQL query statement. Thank you.

Comment: select * from #test where id in (1,2)

is not giving the correct reocordset. No errors, but not the correct recordsets. this only works for when user.task equals a single numbered array e.g. intTask = "2", it does not show the recordset when intTask = "2,3,5". it also fails when there is more than one numbered array in the record e.g. user.task= "2,5,7". Changing the column data types won't yield any differences in the outcome. like i originally asked, any SQL functions to iterate through 2 arrays and compare for matching items ? Thanks in advance

Comment: in that case post the DDL of your tables since I don't know what it looks like or what is stored in it

Comment: Sorry. Ran out of time. I will continue this discussion. For now I'm using the LIKE function. It will give me the proper results, its just not good for performance. The code is: "select user.task from user where user.task like '%"&intTask&"%'". It seems that full text search will be the way to go using arrays.